# Minimizing disk accesses when getting attributes of files in a directory

Tags: file, directory, disk-access

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to get attributes of a large number of files in a directory, but without adding the cost of an additional disk access for each file.

For example, if I get the Name attribute of FileInfo objects in a collection, then there is no additional disk access. However if I get the LastWriteTimeUtc, then an additional disk access is made.

My code:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(myDir);
FileInfo[] allFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (FileInfo fInfo in allFiles)
{
    name = fInfo.Name  //no additional disk access made
    lastMod = fInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc  //further disk access made!!!
}
```

Does anyone know of a way I can get this information in one round trip? I would have hoped that DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() does this but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language? Which operating system(s)?

Comment: Take a look at how it works via Reflector.  The reason that Name doesn't perform additional disk access is because FileInfo stores the name when it's created.  And technically your `GetFiles(...)` call can just be `GetFiles()` as it does the same thing.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Language: c# 3.5, OS(s): Windows 2008R2

@Agent_9191: I have looked at it in Reflector and see what you mean. I'm starting to think that there's no solution other than writing my own component. Also I agree with your point regarding the GetFiles() method call, but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this happens by design. The LastWriteTimeUtc is lazy loaded. So nothing to do other write my own component.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* care about this, you should probably write this in C using FindFirstFile/GetFileTime, etc.